# Editing posts without a clear question

Tags: discussion

So recently  I've come across a few questions that I decide to skip reviewing, or sometimes come across posts that make it hard to guess at what the actual question is. When we run across something like this in the review queue should we just skip it, post a comment about what is the question, or edit it to our best guess?

If I missed this section of the FAQ let me know, but I really am curious how the other people handle trying to figure out what a question is actually asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would caution against editing when you are not sure of the author's intent.

If the post is unclear, post a comment asking for clarification, and skip. When people go through their reviews after the request for clarification, my personal hope is that the community gives the user some time to be able to respond before voting to close.

That said, if the question is so confusing or poorly constructed that it is unlikely that a clear answer would be possible, post a comment in the hopes that it might be salvageable, and vote to close.

Comment: That's so far what I've been doing. Glad I'm handling it in a somewhat sensible way.

Comment: @TildalWave For **Close Reviews** the *I'm Done* option isn't available.  You either *Leave Open*, *Close*, *Edit*, or *Skip*.